# Finding furthest point from origin point using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shortest-path, telecom

I'm using QGIS 3.28 and I need to find the furthest point from an certain origin.

For reference, this is a Fiber to the Home (FTTH) project.

[image: Example]

Imported data:

- The pink dot on the center is the point of origin;
- The thinner green lines are the underground FTTH cables;

Created data:

- 4 polygons (blue, green, purple and red) that divide a bigger zone;
- The thicker lines (blue, red, purple and green) belong to a multistring layer I created. The purpose of them is to represent the path the cable does from the starting point (pink dot) to the furthest point (blue circle);
- The blue circles I manually placed them on the furthest place from the point of origin (while bearing in mind the path that the cable does).

So, what I need in QGIS is to create an easier and faster way to find the places I manually found and placed the blue circles.
Until now I tried to merge the underground cables layer (from numerous features to a single one - MultiLineString), create a shape containing the point of the starting point and using several tools and methods: Shortest path, Least Cost Path, Distance Matrix, Youtube and forums...
And I haven't managed to find a way to do it.

Comment: Is the furthest point you're manually plotting a property or DP, is there an exsisting point already there?

Comment: There's no existing point. Having merged all the lines, I can't find the endpoint (s), or there is?

Comment: You could just go around in circles for ever. You mean furthest point for all possible least cost paths?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'm doing my best to explain myself because i'm not a native English speaker ;)

Answer (score 8):

Few steps to this process but it may be more efficent than the way you're currently working it out - it would be pretty easy to add this into a graphical model/python script too so you dont need to run it manually each time.

Probably much better ways to get it done too but here is my attempt to assist.

**Start Image**
[image: Starting Image]

**Step 1;
Merge Vector Layers** - select all the layers required to make a coherent network from your point of intrest to the furthest 'points' in your networks via lines.

**Step 2;
Extract Vertices** - Extract Vertices of your line layer.
[image: Image of Extract Vertices]

**Step 3;
Select by Location** - Select the new Vertices Layer comparing to your polygon layer.  Ensure you've selected your polygon before hand and click selected features only.

[image: Image of Select by Location]

**Step 4;
Shortest path Point to Layer** - Use your network as the representing network layer (Cables/Duct),
Click on the ... next to start point and select your Starting location or point of intrest.
End points is your new Vertices layer (tick selected features only)

[image: Image of Shortest path Point to Laye]

**Step 5;
Open attribute table** - Sort by cost High > Low (Highest cost line is the furthest point from your POI)

*Image of Attribute table and flashing the highest cost future*
[image: Image of Attribute table and flashing the future]

**Final Overview of all polygons completed**
[image: Image of Final Overview of all polygons completed]

Answer (score 8):

Maybe you can use [Service Area From Point](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html#qgisserviceareafrompoint):

> This algorithm creates a new vector with all the edges or parts of
> edges of a network line layer that can be reached within a distance or
> a time, starting from a point feature. The distance and the time (both
> referred to as "travel cost") must be specified respectively in the
> network layer units or in hours.

I have created a for loop which calculates it multiple times for increasing distances, (mostly for fun). You can just execute the tool manually multiple times.

I started at 50000 meters and increased it until it reached all the furthest ends in the road network:

```py
import random

#Change these two lines to match the names of your layers
line_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("roads")[0]
start_point_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("start_point")[0] #There must be only one point in the layer

#Find the start point
startpoint = [p.geometry() for p in start_point_layer.getFeatures()][0]

colornames = line_layer.renderer().symbol().color().colorNames() #Create a list of color names
areas = [] #A list to hold all the service areas generated
#Create service areas for the distances 50000,55000,60000,65000,...,85000
for distance in range( 50000, 90000, 5000):
    print(f"Calculating service area for distance {distance}...")
    area = processing.run("native:serviceareafrompoint", 
        {'INPUT':line_layer,'STRATEGY':0,'DIRECTION_FIELD':'','VALUE_FORWARD':'',
        'VALUE_BACKWARD':'','VALUE_BOTH':'','DEFAULT_DIRECTION':2,'SPEED_FIELD':'',
        'DEFAULT_SPEED':50,'TOLERANCE':5,
        'START_POINT':startpoint,#'488017.532000,6335277.862250 [EPSG:3006]',
        'TRAVEL_COST2':distance,'INCLUDE_BOUNDS':False,'OUTPUT_LINES':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})["OUTPUT_LINES"]
    area.setName(str(distance)) #Set the layer name
    rend = area.renderer()
    color = rend.symbol().color()
    newcolor = random.choice(colornames)
    color.setNamedColor(newcolor) #And a random color
    rend.symbol().setWidth(0.5) #Line width
    areas.append(area)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers(areas)
```

[image]

It wasnt far enough.

[image]